# javascript: determine functions return type

Tags: javascript

Is there a way in javascript to determine the return type(if any) of a function?

example:

```
function doSomething(){
   return true;
}
```

to returned type is boolean.

example 2:

```
function doSomething2(x){
    if(x=="a") return 1;//number
    else return "bad x"; //string
}
```

Comment: yes, it's called `typeof` http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/determinevar2.shtml

Comment: as your second example shows, there is no such thing as "the return type of a function" in Javascript. So what it seems you're *actually* asking is "is there a way to determine the type of an object". The fact that the object was returned from a function isn't really important. Am I understanding you correctly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check what the type is:

```js
    var x = typeof doSomething2('a');
    
    if (x == "string")
        alert("string")
    else if (x == "number")
        alert("number");
    else if (x == "undefined")
        alert('nothing returned');
    else if (x == "boolean")
        alert("boolean");
    else
        alert(x);
```

A simple shorthand would of course be, assuming `"undefined"` would be fine to return instead of `"nothing returned"`:

```
alert(typeof doSomething2('a'))
```

Example use:

```js
[undefined, 'stringyMeThingy', 42, true, null].forEach(x => console.log(typeof x))
```

Comment: nice. you found a way to make `alert(x);` 10 lines long.

Comment: other than changing "undefined" to "nothing returned", that's effectively what you did..

Comment: alert(x=="undefined"?"nothing returned":x);

Comment: @Pamblam it's a demo, meant to demonstrate return values and types, not a copy paste code... Good day sir.

Comment: I really liked the comment of V. Putin here, but I agree, out of an example/demo point of view, I think it is just fine. What would be nice is if we added a second code block where one could see efficient it could be notated. Everybody happy

Answer (score 5):

This isn't Haskell - Javascript functions can return anything.

Comment: @AdamRackis: Where did I say they return nothing?

Comment: The accepted answer could have mentioned this phrase "Javascript functions can return anything".

Answer (score 4):

No, you are going to have to run the function and check the type of the resulting value.

Comment: I'd say this is about the best answer.  You might also note that a function can be written to return different types of data based on how it's executed (not that that's necessarily a good idea)

Answer (score 2):

```
    function dosomething()
    {
        return true;
    }
    var myfunc=dosomething();
    if(typeof myfunc=="boolean") alert('It is '+typeof myfunc);
```

You can use

```
if(typeof myfunc=="boolean") or if(typeof myfunc=="number") or if(typeof myfunc=="string")
```

or

```
if(typeof myfunc=="object") or if(typeof myfunc=="undefined") to determine the type.
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use it as a function to be return

```js
const determineFunc = (param) => typeof param;

console.log("logs==>", determineFunc(true));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the function is returning object and we apply **typeof** on the returned value, then we will get value as object which is generic type but we may not know what specific object it is,
To get the specific object what i have tried is **constructor.name** which has given the specific object which is returned .Also we have the alternative like
**Object.prototype.toString.call(value)**

**For Example**

```
const li = document.createElement('li');
console.log(typeof li);//object
console.log(li.constructor.name);//HTMLLIElement
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(li));//[object HTMLLIElement]
```

SO we can see `object` is just a generic type for all object.
And `HTMLLIElement` is the specific object returned by the function mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to analyze the return type of a function **without executing it**, you can use the [`ts-morph`](https://ts-morph.com/) library. However, keep in mind that it is a 1mb library primarily used for parsing files, so its usefulness may vary depending on the specific project. An example of using ts-morph to determine the return type of a function is as follows:

```
import { Project } from "ts-morph";

function getReturnType(fn: Function): ts.Type {
  const project = new Project();
  const sourceFile = project.createSourceFile("s.ts", fn.toString());
  return sourceFile.getFunctions()[0].getReturnType().getText()
}

getReturnType(function test(){ return 'test' }) // string
getReturnType(async function test(){ return 'test' }) // Promise<string>
```

Please note that there is an **issue with arrow functions** not working correctly with this code. However, if you know the parameters of the function (for example, if it is a configuration function used in your library), you can **wrap the arrow function in a regular function** and it should work:

```
function getReturnType(fn: Function): ts.Type {
  const project = new Project();
  const functionString = `function(l, n){ return (${fn.toString()})(l, n)}`
  const sourceFile = project.createSourceFile("s.ts", functionString);
  return sourceFile.getFunctions()[0].getReturnType().getText()
}
```